# Texturing Skin with oil/liquids

Tags: animation, texturing

How would i get the type of oil/liquid effect on the skin of a already textured mesh like a Meta Human? Also how could i animate it dripping and rolling down the skin. I'm fairly novice so any links or screenshots would be much appreciated.

[image: Death stranding]

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)